# How to change which axis a colormap acts on

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting a 3D figure in matplotlib, how can I set the colormap to act over the y-values instead of over the z-values which it does by default?

For example, at the moment when I am plotting, the color map acts across the z axis, however I would like it to use the y axis instead, how can I do this?[image]

The arrow shows the direction I want the color to act.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can switch the axis and set the view accordingly:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = np.sin(np.sqrt(X*X + Y*Y))

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Z, Y, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

ax.view_init(elev=120., azim=-90)
fig.colorbar(surf)
```

[image: Original]
[image: Modified]

It is not perfect though but there might be better ways to set the view.